# Using "had" more than once in a sentence

Tags: have

Can I use "had" the way I have in the first sentence? Or is the second sentence correct?

(1) By the time he **had** descended the tree and brought the cat up, the squirrel **had** made a wall of acorns, and the bird **had** fled the scene.

(2) By the time he **had** descended the tree and brought the cat up, the squirrel made a wall of acorns, and the bird fled the scene.

Thanks.

Comment: Either use *had* in every instance, as in the first sentence, or just once, as in the second sentence. Both versions are grammatical; it's a matter of style and personal preference. (You may also find that one version better conveys your specific intent.)

Answer (score -1):

Its a bit of a strange sentence but...  had works for me in 1.

I am not sure if this is what you mean but, I assume [he] descended the tree, grabbed the cat and took it **back** up the tree?  I think adding "back" will make this clearer for the reader, if correct.

Also, I do not think you need the 'Oxford' comma... before the 'and':

**"By the time he had descended the tree and brought the cat [back] up, the squirrel had made a wall of acorns and the bird had fled the scene."**

Sentence 2 does not really work without the 'had'.

I know a good Pest Controller if you continue to have problems with the squirrel...